# Unable to write a CSV into Dropbox APP V2 - CSV appears blank

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload my script's output (pandas df) into a Dropbox folder, but the csv file created in Dropbox appears blank.

```
dbx.files_upload(cvd_tracker.to_csv("Trial.csv"),'/Trial.csv')
```

I'm guessing the .to_csv() doesn't apply here, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I've checked, and the "cvd_tracker" dataframe does have data in it.

Using the StringIO also failed.

```
from io import StringIO
csv_buffer = StringIO()
cvd_tracker.to_csv(csv_buffer)

dbx.files_upload(csv_buffer.getvalue(),'/Trial3.csv')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbx.files_upload` has two required parameters, the first is a file-like object or a bytes-like object, the second is a path in the user's dropbox in which to save the file. Your second parameter looks ok, but your first parameter is incorrect - `pandas.Dataframe.to_csv` returns a string if the first parameter passed to it is `None`, or it returns `None` if the first parameter is not `None`. The first (and only) parameter you pass to `cvd_tracker.to_csv` is `"Trial.csv"`, so `cvd_tracker.to_csv("Trial.csv")` returns `None`. This means essentially you are doing `dbx.files_upload(None, "/Trial.csv")`.

To get the desired result, simply remove the argument passed to `cvd_tracker.to_csv`, so that it returns a string. You then need to turn the string into a bytes-like object by using `str.encode`, so that `dbx.files_upload` can accept it. It would look like this:

`dbx.files_upload(cvd_tracker.to_csv().encode(), "/Trial.csv")`

Comment: If i remove the argument to to_csv,I get an error.
>> TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class 'str'>

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py in request_json_string(self, host, func_name, route_style, request_json_arg, request_binary, timeout)
    520             # request fails and needs to be re-tried at a later time.
    521             raise TypeError('expected request_binary as binary type, got %s' %
--> 522                             type(request_binary))
    523 
    524         # Fully qualified hostname

TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class 'str'>

Comment: @HemanshuDas I found another documentation that indicates that `dbx.files_upload` doesn't actually accept strings, but rather a bytes-like object. Try this: `dbx.files_upload(cvd_tracker.to_csv().encode(), "/Trial.csv")`

Comment: Voila! That works. You are a life saver. Thanks a lot.
Do you mind updating the answer for others benefit.